# Failed to push some refs to?

Tags: git, github

I have installed the git and customized it, then I have tried to push repository. But it didn't do to push. Git say error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/HeartOfProgrammer/PHP-CODES.git'
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the actual message is:

```
git 'lfs' is not a git command.
error: failed to push some refs
```

As [mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/333#issuecomment-105500557):

> Sorry for the trouble, you should be able to fix your pushes by removing the `.git/hooks/pre-push` file from your repository. This is where git is trying to run git lfs when you push.

You can also [make sure lfs is completely uninstalled](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/316#issuecomment-103751725).

---

Original answer:

The complete message should include an Hint about "non-fast-forward updates were rejected".

It is possible that you have:

- created a repo on GitHub with  a `README` (one commit done there)
- created an empty repo locally (0 commit, then your own commit), add a remote and tried to push.

In that case, you would have two different history.

Try a `git pull --rebase`, then `git push`.

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand you well. I have done so  http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1508/4f/e0ce02a75c37.png

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer I now see the *full* and complete error message. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nothing hasn't changed, Shall I delete the programm git? And I install again?

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer which version of Git are you suing? On which OS?

Comment: version 2.5.0
Release Notes (2015-07-27). OS my Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer 2.5 is not yet released. Uninstall your current version, and uncompress (no setup) https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases the 2.4.6 anywhere you want. Add it to your %PATH% and try again.

Comment: I have deleted git and I have downloaded your git and installed it, Then I tried to do all over again , and again did not work http://s020.radikal.ru/i707/1508/63/12642231d29f.png

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer if the error message still mention lfs, follow https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/316#issuecomment-103751725

Answer (score 0):

error failed to push some refs to 'https //github.com/'username'
for this kind of error Goto https://github.com/settings/profile/emails
and remove the tick mark   on ("Block command line pushes that expose my email")
an again try command git push.
 still  if you are not able to  do  that then use command #git pull and after that use 
command #git push.